# Does using TaskCompleteSource.Wait block the thread that creates it?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I've got a `Task`.  It creates a `TaskCompletionSource` and `Wait`s for some other thing to set its `Result`.

In the call to `myTaskCompletionSource.Wait()`:

1. Is the thread that created it blocked?
2. Can TPL reuse the thread to service other tasks?

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` does not contain a `Wait()`, is `myTaskCompletionSource` really the output of `realTaskCompletionSource.Task`? Please include some code showing what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The thread that called `myTaskCompletionSource.Wait()` gets blocked, the creator of myTaskCompletionSource is not affected by the call.
2. No, the thread is totally blocked. if you wanted the thread to be available for other tasks you would need to `await` on it via `await myTaskCompletionSource;`.